# javascript parseFloat not working for date sorting in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

HI trying to sort with date but the below code working fine chrome but not working in IE11, can any one help me please what is the change here.
find the code below

```
sort(ev, sortProperty) {

    if (ev.target.innerText === '▲') {
      // ascending  html code

      ev.target.innerHTML = '&#x25bc;'

      this.summary.sort(function (a, b) {

        if (sortProperty === 'hubDueDate') {
          console.log("ascending1");
          const valb = new Date(b[sortProperty]);
          const vala = new Date(a[sortProperty]);
          return valb.getTime() - vala.getTime();
        } else {
          console.log("descending");
          return parseFloat(b[sortProperty]) - parseFloat(a[sortProperty]);

        }
      });
    } else {
      // sorting descending order
      ev.target.innerHTML = '&#x25b2;'
      this.summary.sort(function (a, b) {

        if (sortProperty === 'hubDueDate') {
          console.log("descending1");
          const valb = new Date(b[sortProperty]);
          const vala = new Date(a[sortProperty]);
          return vala.getTime() - valb.getTime();
        } else {
          console.log("descending");
          return parseFloat(a[sortProperty]) - parseFloat(b[sortProperty]);

        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: this.summary is service call for data table like
this._summaryService.getSummary().subscribe(
        summary => {
}

Comment: initially angularjs 2 now its 4

Comment: Angular and AngularJS are completely different, you can't tag them as something the same, otherwise people can't help you

Comment: we are using angular2 but its working in chrome and other browsers but not in IE11